# Can't build Concorde TSP solver on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, build, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to build the Concorde TSP solver (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/downloads/downloads.htm) on my Macbook.

There are various websites that describe how to do this, such as http://wiki.evilmadscientist.com/Obtaining_a_TSP_solver#Concorde_TSP_on_Macs

However, the build process fails with the following errors:

```
make[1]: *** [verify.o] Error 1
make: *** [concorde.a] Error 2</code>
```

I can't seem to find any recent sites that describe anyone having the same problem as me, nor any sites that specifically mention building Concorde under Yosemite.  Am I doing something wrong, or does this just not work with Yosemite?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Actually, the error you mentioned is kind of summary, not a root cause error. You need to check compilation output for the real error.